# Почему while update не работает и должен ли вообще работать?

Tags: php

```
do {
    mysql_query("UPDATE vagony SET stancya_stoyank = '$p1' WHERE typ_vag = $p") or die(mysql_error());
} while ($v == $k);

if($v < $k) break;
```

Comment: А что в $v и $k и какой вообще смысл в этом куске?)

А вообще все просто. Если $v == k, - зацикливание, если нет - "цикл" пройдет 1 раз.

Comment: Пока v равно k... То есть, либо цикл выполнится 1 раз, либо уйдет в бесконечность, потому что ни v, ни k в цикле не меняются.

Comment: Тогда как написать условие? Нужно, чтобы update выполнялся пока v и k не станут равны.
По идее, там стоят количества вагонов, которые имеются на станции - k и которые необходимо - v

Comment: А "typ_vag" - это что? Тип вагона? Т.е., например, для пассажирских - общий, плацкарт, купе, для грузовых - цистерна, вагон и т.д.? У вас тогда в запросе ошибка - он все вагоны с данным типом отправит на данную станцию. И лучше использовать: mysql_query("UPDATE vagony SET stancya_stoyank = '".$p1."' WHERE typ_vag = ".$p) - строковая интерполяция занимает больше процессорного времени чем конкатенация строк

Comment: задолбали вы уже своими кавычками и "интерполяциями", главное чтобы читабельно было, а экономят на кавычках только шизики
И да, интерполяция вдвое быстрее чем конкатенация http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: @Герман а некрофилы поднимают древние темы ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
while($k <= $v){
    ++$k;
    // update БД
}
// через do{}while(); цикл может выполниться лишний раз, если $k > $v
```

Comment: как сделать так чтобы update был только на одну строчку, а не на все сразу ?

Comment: Надо убрать цикл.

Answer (score 1):

```
 do {
        ++$k; // не в курсе на счет php 
   ... 
  }  (while $k < $v);
```